# Take ID from drop down list and drop details

Tags: c#, combobox, visual-studio-2017, truncate

I have a drop down list (Works as needed) but I want to be able to add details to the list when I am selecting an ID it will show the customer/venue's name so you don't have to memorise every ID. I want to drop the name after its selected and keep the ID but I can't get it by itself. 
[image: Code to display and add ID]

[image: Drop down list (OPENED)]
[image: Drop down list after selecting a value]

Comment: There are a number of things I'ld change in that code. The way you fill those combos would be the first. Since you use `List<[Class]>` to store your data, you could use those Lists as the datasource of your combos, adding some properties to the classes to use as `DisplayMember` (with a pre-formatted output) and `ValueMember`. Then use the `SelectedValue` (referencing the ID) of the selected item to filter your `List<Venue>`. Using spaces to define the columns of the dropdownlist is also not a great solution with proportional fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you reviewed how to implement combo box control?  I believe you can bind data source and then configure the "value" and display properties so that its selected index would reveal value (the Id in your data set) while the displayed portion would show a user friendly name of your data.

Refer to... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-a-windows-forms-combobox-or-listbox-control-to-data